# Slow pg_test_fsync on SSD Raid

Tags: postgresql

Sometimes I experience slow writing performance on my dedicated (SSD Software Raid 1) server with PostgreSQL 9.5. I ran `pg_test_fsync` and results are not really good. Actually there are much better on my laptop.

```
5 seconds per test
O_DIRECT supported on this platform for open_datasync and open_sync.

Compare file sync methods using one 8kB write:
(in wal_sync_method preference order, except fdatasync is Linux's default)
        open_datasync                                n/a*
        fdatasync                           142.923 ops/sec    6997 usecs/op
        fsync                               286.576 ops/sec    3489 usecs/op
        fsync_writethrough                            n/a
        open_sync                                    n/a*
* This file system and its mount options do not support direct
I/O, e.g. ext4 in journaled mode.

Compare file sync methods using two 8kB writes:
(in wal_sync_method preference order, except fdatasync is Linux's default)
        open_datasync                                n/a*
        fdatasync                           249.736 ops/sec    4004 usecs/op
        fsync                               296.435 ops/sec    3373 usecs/op
        fsync_writethrough                            n/a
        open_sync                                    n/a*
* This file system and its mount options do not support direct
I/O, e.g. ext4 in journaled mode.

Compare open_sync with different write sizes:
(This is designed to compare the cost of writing 16kB in different write
open_sync sizes.)
         1 * 16kB open_sync write                    n/a*
         2 *  8kB open_sync writes                   n/a*
         4 *  4kB open_sync writes                   n/a*
         8 *  2kB open_sync writes                   n/a*
        16 *  1kB open_sync writes                   n/a*

Test if fsync on non-write file descriptor is honored:
(If the times are similar, fsync() can sync data written on a different
descriptor.)
        write, fsync, close                 266.308 ops/sec    3755 usecs/op
        write, close, fsync                   0.513 ops/sec  1949165 usecs/op

Non-sync'ed 8kB writes:
        write                            145663.483 ops/sec       7 usecs/op
```

I also ran `dd` to see writing speed:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output bs=8k count=10k; rm -f /tmp/output
10240+0 records in
10240+0 records out
83886080 bytes (84 MB, 80 MiB) copied, 0.0765848 s, 1.1 GB/s
```

Once again. Writing speed is better on my laptop. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

P.S. I've been using `zfs` filesystem.

Comment: You mean `zfs`? How about trying with `ext4` or `xfs`?

Comment: Yes, of course - `zfs`. Hmm, I don't know. It's production environment and I can't change it so easily (and I don't know how :)) Do you think, file system might be a problem?

Comment: zfs seems to be one of the slowest options https://blog.pgaddict.com/posts/postgresql-performance-on-ext4-and-xfs here is a blog post about tuning zfs for Postgres: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/pg-phriday-postgres-zfs/

Comment: The role of "pg_test_fsync" is to take the actual database out of the equation by running the relevant sync operations directly.  So since you have done that and seen the results, I think your question would be better suited for a less database-centric forum.  Perhaps server fault?